# What is this green plant that is growing in my garden?

Tags: identification

I have this plant growing in my garden, and I want to know if it is a weed, or if it gives off food. I live in North Carolina, United States.

Here are my two pictures:

[image: unknown green plant]

[image: unknown green plant]